# Custom Transition for sap.m.App

Tags: sapui5

I want to write a custom transition for sap.m.Page transitions.
How Do I start off with this?
Exactly I want to know regarding any documentation, How to create a custom transition and register the same so that it can be used in an SAP UI5 Application.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The documentation can be found at [addCustomTransition](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainer.html#addCustomTransition). To see how we can implement our own, take a look at the source code of [other transitions here](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.48.5/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/NavContainer.js#L1042).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Sample implementation of custom transition when App navigates. Click on the list item to find the transition. There is no documentaion on it. This is just a hack.

```js
        jQuery.sap.require('sap.m.NavContainer');
  jQuery.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-core');
  jQuery.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-effect')
  jQuery.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-effects-core');
  jQuery.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-effects-clip');
  
                sap.m.NavContainer.transitions["custom"] = {
 
   to: function(oFromPage, oToPage, fCallback) {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
     oFromPage.$().toggle("clip");
     oToPage.$().toggle("clip");
     fCallback();
    },600);
    
   },
 
   back: function(oFromPage, oToPage, fCallback) {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
     debugger;
     oFromPage.$().toggle("clip");
     oToPage.$().toggle("clip");
     fCallback();
    },600);
   }
 };/* code for transition */


var data = {
    names: [
     {firstName: "Peter", lastName: "Mueller"},
     {firstName: "Petra", lastName: "Maier"},
     {firstName: "Thomas", lastName: "Smith"},
     {firstName: "John", lastName: "Williams"},
     {firstName: "Maria", lastName: "Jones"}
    ]
   };
   
   // create a Model with this data
   var model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
   model.setData(data);
 
   var list = new sap.m.List({
    headerText:"Names"
   });
   
   list.bindItems({
    path : "/names", 
    sorter : new sap.ui.model.Sorter("lastName"),
    template : new sap.m.StandardListItem({
     title: "{lastName}",
     description: "{firstName}",
     type: sap.m.ListType.Navigation,
     press:function(evt){
      var oBindingContext = evt.getSource().getBindingContext(); 
      page2.setBindingContext(oBindingContext); 
      app.to("page2","custom");
     }
    })
   });
   
   // create the page holding the List
   var page1 = new sap.m.Page("page1",{
    title: "List Page",
    content : list
   });
   
   // create the detail page
   var page2 = new sap.m.Page("page2", {
    title: "Detail Page",
    showNavButton: true,
    navButtonPress: function(){
     app.back();
    },
    content : [
     new sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm({ 
      title: "Details for {firstName} {lastName}",
      content: [
       new sap.m.Label({text: "First Name"}),
       new sap.m.Text({text: "{firstName}"}),
       new sap.m.Label({text: "Last Name"}),
       new sap.m.Text({text: "{lastName}"})
      ]
     })
    ]
   });
   
   // create a mobile App holding the pages and place the App into the HTML document
   var app = new sap.m.App({
    pages: [page1, page2]
   }).placeAt("content");
   
   // set the model to the App; it will be propagated to the children
   app.setModel(model);
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <title>Custom jQuery transition</title>
  
  <script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" 
    id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.layout" 
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"></script>
  
 </head>
 <body id="content" class="sapUiBody">
 </body>
</html>
```